# Search filter from JSON is not working on children object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, recursion, filter

```
import Sidebaritems from "./Sidebaritems";
import data from "../data.json";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Sidebar() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <input
        className="search"
        type="text "
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
      {data
        .filter((item) => {
          if (search === "") {
            return item;
          } else if (item?.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
            return item;
          }
        })
        .map((item, index) => (
          <Sidebaritems key={index} item={item} search={search} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is my code for search bar and filter from JSON but when I input name in search bar it only filter parent not child
from JSON

```
 {
        "name": "India",
        "moduleId": 1,
        "parentId": 0,

        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Rajasthan",
                "moduleId": 6,
                
                "parentId": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Kota",
                        "moduleId": 11,
                        "parentId": 6,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "Form1",
                                "moduleId": 16,
                                "parentId": 11,
                                "path": "/Form-1"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Form2",
                                "moduleId": 17,
                                "parentId": 11
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Form3",
                                "moduleId": 18,
                                "parentId": 11
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Form4 ",
                                "moduleId": 19,
                                "parentId": 11
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Form5",
                                "moduleId": 20,
                                "parentId": 11
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Jaipur",
                        "moduleId": 12,
                        "parentId": 5,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "form6",
                                "moduleId": 21,
                                "parentId": 12
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "form7 ",
                                "moduleId": 22,
                                "parentId": 12
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "form8",
                                "moduleId": 23,
                                "parentId": 12
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "form9",
                                "moduleId": 24,
                                "parentId": 12
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "form10",
                                "moduleId": 25,
                                "parentId": 12
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Udaipur",
                        "moduleId": 13,
                        "parentId": 5,
                        "children": [
                            
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "jhalawar",
                        "moduleId": 14,
                        "parentId": 5,
                        "children": [
                            
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Rajsamand",
                        "moduleId": 15,
                        "parentId": 5,
                        "children": [
                          
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Gujarat",
                "moduleId": 7,
                "parentId": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Rajkot",
                        "moduleId": 41,
                        "parentId": 7,
                        "children": [
                           
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Ahmedabad",
                        "moduleId": 42,
                        "parentId": 5,
                        "children": [
                            
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Surat",
                        "moduleId": 43,
                        "parentId": 5,
                        "children": [
                            
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "xyz",
                        "moduleId": 44,
                        "parentId": 5,
                        "children": [
                          
                        ]
                    }
                   
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Panjab",
                "moduleId": 8,
                "parentId": 1,
                "children": [
                    
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Goa",
                "moduleId": 9,
                "parentId": 1,
                "children": [
                    
                    
                ]
            }
          
        ]
    },
```

Comment: can you please add json

Comment: While it's pronounced "Jason", it's never written out that way. It's either json or JSON

Comment: @ShamPooSham I would say that it should only be JSON as it's an initialism (JavaScript Object Notation)

Comment: @SrushtiShah jason added

Comment: Why would it be recursive? The built-in filter isn’t recursive.

Comment: @DaveNewton no could you somthing in filter merthod that it will work on child and grand child

Comment: You could write a recursive filter, sure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think making a recursive filter that can both handle the value of parent and their children object can be confusing at the end for the user.
The user prefer to know what they are doing using an website.

I would suggest to make several filters that can be added on top on the default search filters.
It would require you to write a Callback that handle an array of filter for your **array.prototype.filter()** function.
For each filter in your array, you can add a condition function using an object and use it for checking your object.
Like this:

```
{
   id:1,
   name:'nonVeg',
   value:"nonVeg",
   condition(a) {return a?.veg === 0},
   isActive:false
},
```

Then with an **array.prototype.every()** function, you check if your object check every condition of your active filter.
Hope this help.